# UITabBarController + UINavigationController problem xcode project

Tags: xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a problem, I have created a project window based application in xcode, then I create a `UITabBarController` that manages two views all programmatically, the second view is a tableView and I want to see in the top a `UINavigationController`, I have tried a lot but I don't know how to have a `UINavigationController` in the second view. this is the code:

**ProjectAppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    //Creo una tabBarController
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    //Create the two view controllers
    UIViewController *vc1 = [[Visuale1ViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *vc2 = [[Visuale2ViewController alloc] init];

    //Make an array containing the two view controllers
    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1, vc2, nil];

    //The viewControllers array retains vc1 and vc2, we can release
    //our ownership of them in this method
    [vc1 release];
    [vc2 release];

    //Attach them to the tab bar controller
    [tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];

    //Setto la tabBarController come rootViewController di window
    [window setRootViewController:tabBarController];

    //The window retain tabBarController, possiamo lasciare il nostro riferimento
    [tabBarController release];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

**Visuale1ViewController.h**

```
@implementation Visuale1ViewController

- (id)init{

    [super initWithNibName:@"Visuale1ViewController" bundle:nil];
    //Get the tab bar item
    UITabBarItem *tbi = [self tabBarItem];

    //Give it a label
    [tbi setTitle:@"Visuale 1"];

    return self;
}

// The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)bundle {
    return [self init];
}
```

**Visuale2ViewController.h**

```
@implementation AnswerViewController

- (id)init{
    //Call the superclass's designated initializer
    /*[super initWithNibName:nil
                                    bundle:nil];*/
    [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

    answers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i<10 ; i++) {
            [answers addObject:[Answer DefaultAnswer]];
    }
    //Get the tab bar item
    UITabBarItem *tbi = [self tabBarItem];

    //Give it a laber
    [tbi setTitle:@"Visuale 2"];

    return self;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style{
    return [self init];
}

//All below are all methods to work the table view, and all go well, the only problem it's the UINavigationController, to manage then the detail of the table...
```

Now I want to know how I can put a `UINavigationController` in the second view. I try do this, in **ProjectAppDelegate.m:**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    //Creo una tabBarController
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    //Create the two view controllers
    UIViewController *vc1 = [[Visuale1ViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *vc2 = [[Visuale2ViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc2];

    //Make an array containing the two view controllers
    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1, navController, nil];

    //The viewControllers array retains vc1 and vc2, we can release
    //our ownership of them in this method
    [vc1 release];
    [vc2 release];

    //Attach them to the tab bar controller
    [tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];

    //Setto la tabBarController come rootViewController di window
    [window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
}
```

In this way I can visualize the NavigationBar, but I lost the name of the SecondTabBar. Sorry for my english, how I can do this?

Comment: You are going right then what's your problem, can you please more specify about it "but i lost the name of the SecondTabBar"

Comment: ok, u see that vc1 have setTitle:@"Visuale1" and vc2 have title "Visuale2"...when i add the uiNAvigationController i can't see the title of the vc2...why?

Answer (score 0):

Yes in the second view you have to set title as

[self.navigationItem setTitle:@"Visuale2"];

Comment: i know this, but i lost the title in the TabBarItem...i can't see the tapBarItem title Visuale2...

Answer (score 0):

For TabBar title-

UITabBar *tabBar = [self.tabBarController tabBar];

NSArray *tabBarItems = [tabBar items];

UITabBarItem *secondTabBarItem = [tabBarItems objectAtIndex:1];

[secondTabBarItem setTitle:@"Visuale2"];

Comment: one thing i want to suggest you that why are you doing this by code complexing when you have options of XIB

Comment: because i prefer do it programmatically, but the code you write in what class i have to put it??...u look my class? in Visuale2ViewController.h i have the code to display the tabbar title...why don't work when i put on the UINavigationController? the problem is that whitout the UINavigationController i can see the title, with the navigationController the title disappear...

Comment: you can paste this code after setting tabBarcontroller's view controller.

Comment: can you plz NSLog self before UITabBarItem *tbi = [self tabBarItem];
 check what does it contains now?

Comment: i what class i have to put it?ProjectAppDelegate.m?

Comment: below this line in app delegate [tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];

Comment: if i past that code give me that error: error: request for member 'tabBarController' in something not a structure or union

Comment: use what reference variable you are using for UITabBarController

Comment: i add answer up look...i don't know why now works with UIImage

Answer (score 0):

I left the code as it was and I added in init Visale2ViewController this:

```
UIImage *i = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Hypno.png"];
[tbi setImage:i];
```

and now in can see the text Visuale2 in tabBar and the image...i don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `tabBarItem` property for your `UINavigationController`. Something like this.

```
    UITabBarItem *tabItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Visuale 2" image:nil tag:1];      
    UIViewController *vc2 = [[Visuale2ViewController alloc] init];

    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc2];
    navController.tabBarItem = tabItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking at it,the scenario seems to be same like me.What I faced for the first time when doing Tab+Navigation.

I am sure that there is some problem with your Tab+Navigation based application. Although it shows the Tab as well as navigation are not able to navigate the basic flow.And it is very difficult to solve your problem with such less code.

Instead of this, I had an alternate solution for the same:

Once you have a tab bar in a XIB, the easiest way to approach this is to drag a UINavigationController object over from the Library window (looks like a left nav bar button on a gold background) into the Tree View for your tab bar (the text only view, not the GUI). Place it under the tab bar, then drag your existing view controller under the tab bar controller instead of under the tab bar.

When you go to view that tab you should then see a navigation bar on the top of it... if you are loading the navigation controller from another xib, you'll modify the nav bar in the tab bar xib.

else you can below you can follow the best url for the same:

http://books.google.co.in/books?id=2yYlm_2ktFYC&pg=PA179&lpg=PA179&dq=navigation+with+the+tab+based+application+iphoneSDK&source=bl&ots=nf2YYjX5Am&sig=COpHj9wOtsDChQBglpsljSTsElw&hl=en&ei=3ZoFTeGSOI_tsgbc_Iz6CQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CDAQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q&f=false

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBnPfAtswgw

Hope this will surely solve your problem.

Comment: @Alay, I think @Piero's code works fine, he was just asking how to show the title on the tab bar. It is actually easier to do stuff from code than with IB. IB just complicates stuff...